# Disable (or customize) the "grow" animation for Cairo dock

Tags: customization, dock

Is there a way in which I can customize (or disable) the "grow on hover" animation in Cairo dock? I have the size set to the smallest possible and would like to disable the hover animation because it's really annoying, and difficult to work with when enabled. In the least, I would like to be able to specify how many pixels it'll grow when hovered over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Cairo Dock [FAQ](http://www.glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=F.A.Q&lang=en):

> **I find the dock too flashy, can it be more sober?**
>
> Tip: try different themes, some are already very sober, like Dust-Sand or Elementary.
>   When you can do more you can do less ! You can for instance deactivate the "Icon effects" plug-in,
>   or deactivate the effect on mouse hovering in "Animated Icon" plug-in.
>   **You can also decrease the zoom effect or lower the icons' reflect in the "Icon" module,**
>   change the background colors in the "Background" module, or change the view to the "default" view in the "Views" module.
>   In brief, you can easily have something as sober as a gnome-panel, but this would be a shame ! ^_^

Right click on the dock, `Cairo-Dock -> Configure` go to the `Icons` module and change the `Maximum zoom of the icons` setting to `1` and the icons will no longer "grow" when you hover over them.